# PHP "Cancel" line of code

Tags: php, python

I am using phpseclib to ssh to my server and run a python script. The python script is an infinite loop, so it runs until you stop it. When I execute python script.py via ssh with phpseclib, it works, but the page just loads for ever. It does this because phpseclib does not think it is "done" running the line of code that runs the infinite loop script so it hangs on that line. I have tried using exit and die after that line, but of course, it didnt work because it hangs on the line before, the one that executes the command. Does any one have any ideas on how I can fix this without modifying the python file? Thanks.

Comment: What do you want it to do? Start the Python script and let it keep running without the PHP script?

Comment: @icktoofay Yes, then I have another button to stop it which runs "kilall python" the stop button works, but I would just like to eliminate the page always "loading" so the user can do other stuff while the script is running.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the command will be run by a shell, you could have it execute this to start it:

```
nohup python myscript.py > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Comment: Execute that via ssh? The script uses parameters also like p.py 1111111111 How would I put those in?

Comment: @CJSculti: Put them after `myscript.py` and before `>`.

Answer (score 0):

If you put an & on the end of any shell command it will run in the background and return immediately, that's all you really need.

Comment: Wouldn't `SIGHUP` kill it then?

Comment: Depends, not all programs honor that signal

Comment: If it depends, then you should probably account for that in your answer.

Comment: :-) true. I checked python does honor that signal through the CLI so it would be killed.

Answer (score 0):

Something else you could have also done:

```
$ssh->setTimeout(1);
```